# Sorting out lookup values while getting them

Tags: 2007, development, list, lookup-column, query

I have two lists,

```
List A [Document Number, Name, Title,...] (document library)
List B [Information Number, Name, Title, Document Number] (simple list)
```

Now List B is getting all documents from List A as lookup column and letting user add documents name to List B specific Information Number, which can have 0, 1 or many documents.

I wonder what would be the best way to get all lookup fields values (document's name but no duplicates) that are associated with any Information Number item in a ascending order by Information Number.

For example:

```
List B, 

       Item A -   Document 1, Document 9, Document 3
       Item B -   DOcument 2, Document 3, Document 4, Document 5
       Item C -   Document 1, Document 5, Document 9, Document 0.8
```

Now the output I would like is something like this,

```
Document 1, Document 9, Document 3, Document 2, Document 4, Document 5, Document 0.8
```

Can I use CAML query or through C# code, and an example code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a version of .net that support LINQ you can use the Distinct function after a conversion of your value:

```
var collectionWithDistinctElements = oldArray.Distinct().ToArray();
```

otherwise you can use the hast table

```
var list = new HashSet<string> { };
list.Add("a");
list.Add("a");

var countItems = list.Count(); //in this case countItems=1
```

Comment: Your answer seems alright but I tried a different way to achieve what I wanted, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I used SPQuery to get list items from both lists and then filtered the only ones I need. After I stored them in a List class and used IComparable class to sort them out accordingly.

Hope it helps if anyone else encountered same problem.

Comment: maybe this way is slowest than use a hash table (I'm not pretty sure)

Comment: I had to perform some additional things to documents which I couldn't do with hashset :) but it comes down to requirements.